# How to make the links generated on sitemap with https protocol instead of http - Python script (Django framework)

Tags: python, django, http, https, sitemap

I have a Python script (Django framework) it automatically generates links in sitemap but it only generates HTTP links, I want the links to be HTTPS

this is what sitemap.py have

```
    from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from .models import Theme

class ThemeSitemap(Sitemap):
changefreq = 'weekly'
priority = 0.8
def items(self):
return Theme.objects.all().order_by('-id')
```

I tried to add

```
protocol = "https"
```

but it did not work

How can I fix that?

Comment: How are the links being generated? Does OP store them in the database with the https? Also, how does the template that generates the link look like?

Comment: According to the documentation `https` is now the default https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#django.contrib.sitemaps.Sitemap.protocol

Comment: Why are you setting `changefreq` and `priority`? Google ignores those fields.  They just bloat your sitemap. Usually your sitemaps should only have `<loc>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
protocol = "https"
```

is the right solution, I just had to be more careful with spaces.

Comment: Glad you found an answer, and thank you for sharing!